# CDI Observer condition in @Dependent bean

Tags: java, cdi

I have a abstract super class:

```
public abstract class A<T extends Other> extends B {...}
```

Another class defined with `@ViewScoped` and `@Named` is extending A:

```
public class C extends A<OtherSub> implements Serializable {...}
```

So far this is no problem.

Now I would like to add observer methods in the super class `A` to generically handle CDI events, e.g.:

```
public void entityCreated(@Observes(notifyObserver = Reception.IF_EXISTS) @Created EntityChangedEvent event) {...}
```

But deploying this wildfly throws an exception during deployment:

> WELD-000404: Conditional observer method cannot be declared by a @Dependent scoped bean: [BackedAnnotatedMethod] public A.entityCreated(@Observes @Created EntityChangedEvent)

I know that I can create the observer without the `notifyObserver` condition, but this has the effect, that other beans will be created and notified upon the CDI event, which I would like to prevent.

Is there any way to use the `notifyObserver` condition in the generic super class? Or do I need to use it without that condition respectively implement it in the concrete subclass?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just looking at CDI 1.2 spec, [section 10.4.4 Conditional observer methods](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.2/cdi-spec.html#conditional_observer_methods):

> Beans with scope @Dependent may not have conditional observer methods.

Therefore your request is invalid in this regard and it cannot work.One of the reasons I can glance for this is that `@Dependent` beans are not normal scoped and basically can exist "within given context" (note the quotes) 0-n times. Hence you would have some ambiguity in notifications. In comparison, normal scoped beans will exist 0-1 time in given context, so it's pretty straightforward there.

Therefore you will have to stick to non-conditional observer method for your `@Dependent` beans.

Comment: But the implementing class (in the example `C`) has a normal scope and therefore conforms to the spec. The problem in my eyes is that I cannot define the scope on the abstract super class `A` and this causes the problem.

Comment: @GeorgHenkel sorry, I missed the fact that `C` is `ViewScoped`. In that case it really should work, I just tried dummy CDI SE app with `C` being normal scoped bean and it works just fine. Can you make sure it's `javax.faces.view.ViewScoped` (and *not* `javax.faces.bean`)?

Comment: Thanks for your test. I have also rechecked my setup and found other subclasses of `A` which didn't have a scope defined (were created by a fellow who also works on the project). These were causing the error and not that classes I was watching.

Comment: Makes sense, glad you nailed it down :)